# Issue running wireguard (wg-quick) on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, wireguard

I'm trying to run wireguard on a VPS running Ubuntu. My config works find on MacOS using the wireguard GUI. but when I run it on the VPS using `wg-quick` I get the following output, the SSH connection freezes, and I can't reconnect. Eventually I have to restart the VPS to be able to connect to it. And when I restart, I can't find any useful logs to see what went wrong.

```
root@srv1397230242:~# wg-quick up ~/wg0.conf 
[#] ip link add wg0 type wireguard
[#] wg setconf wg0 /dev/fd/63
[#] ip -4 address add <MY_IP>/32 dev wg0
[#] ip -6 address add fd00::9:7e38/128 dev wg0
[#] ip link set mtu 1280 up dev wg0
[#] resolvconf -a tun.wg0 -m 0 -x
[#] wg set wg0 fwmark 51820
[#] ip -4 route add 0.0.0.0/0 dev wg0 table 51820
```

Can you help me set it up correctly?

Note:

- Allowed IPs in my config don't interfere with my SSH connection.
- No firewall is active
- No other service is running on 51820

Comment: Usually a VPS server serves clients to use a VPN through it. Here you're configuring the VPS typically like you would a client: have the VPN for everything. That's not how you should configure it.

Comment: Can you provide the wg-quick's full configuration (just obfuscate keys and pubic addresses if needed) for the VPS and also one of its matching peer?